# Scoring system for a quiz

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the scoring system to work right?
It adds +1 if it's correct, but + an even bigger number if it's wrong...I just want it to add +1 to both.

It should post only +1 for wrong...

HTML

```
<div>
  <h5>What do you say to begin a game in No Game No Life?</h5>
  <input class='question1' id='question1'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>What color is Mumen Rider's helmet in One Punch Man?</h5>
  <input class='question2' id='question2'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Are Goku's new Super Saiyan Forms too ridiculous?</h5>
  <input class='question3' id='question3' placeholder='Yes or No?'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>What is the Answer to Life's Problems?</h5>
  <input class='question4' id='question4' placeholder='Love or Fear?'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>In Season 2 of SAO, is the main character a girl, boy, or both?</h5>
  <input class='question5' id='question5'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Who is the best character in One Piece?</h5>
  <input class='question6' id='question6'>
  </h5>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Finish this quote from Gurren Lagann, "TO THE ( )!!!!!"</h5>
  <input class='question7' id='question7'>
</div>
<button id='button' type='button' onclick='answer()'>Do you even anime?</button>
</form>

<span class='correct'>
  <label for='score'>CORRECT</label>
  <input type='text' id='score'>
</span>
<span class='wrong'>
  <label for='wrong'>WRONG</label>
  <input type='text' id='wrong'>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var quizArray = [
  { answer: 'ashente' },
  { answer: 'green' },
  { answer: 'yes' },
  { answer: 'love' },
  { answer: 'both' },
  { answer: 'chopper' },
  { answer: 'heavens' }
]

function answer() {
  var correct = 0;
  var wrong = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    var question1 = document.getElementById('question1').value;
    if (question1 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
  var question2 = document.getElementById('question2').value;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question2 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
  var question3 = document.getElementById('question3').value;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question3 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
  var question4 = document.getElementById('question4').value;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question4 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
  var question5 = document.getElementById('question5').value;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question5 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
  var question6 = document.getElementById('question6').value;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question6 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
  var question7 = document.getElementById('question7').value;
  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question7 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how the incrementing is implemented in the for-loops.  Let's take the first loop as an example:

You are trying to assess whether or not question 1 has been answered correctly by comparing the users answer with every possible answer in the quizArray element.  With 7 questions we should have 7 iterations of the loop.  In each iteration, you check if the answer for question 1 is correct and increment the correct variable accordingly.  Otherwise you increment the wrong variable.  So for 7 iterations of the for-loop you are incrementing the wrong variable at least 6 times.

Instead of trying to increment the correct and wrong variables in each iteration, you can use a flag to determine if the question was answered correctly, and then increment the variables after the loop.  For example:

```
var correct = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var question1 = document.getElementById('question1').value;
var answerCorrect = false;
for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question1 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      answerCorrect = true;
    }
}
if (answerCorrect){
  correct += 1;
  document.getElementById('score').value = correct      
}
else {
  wrong += 1;
  document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong
}

answerCorrect = false; 
var question2 = document.getElementById('question2').value;
for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (question2 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      answerCorrect = true;
    }
}
if (answerCorrect){
  correct += 1;
  document.getElementById('score').value = correct      
}
else {
  wrong += 1;
  document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong
}
```

Comment: can't get it to work still. What do you mean "//Dont forget to reset flag to false before next checks"

Comment: Before starting with the next for loop you need to "reset" the answerCorrect flag to false so it does not yield incorrect results.  

What error are you running into now?  It's hard to know whats going on without seeing the quizArray object.

Comment: So I would need to add this part to each loop? :
    if (question1 == quizArray[i].answer) {
      answerCorrect = true;
    }
}
if (answerCorrect){
  correct += 1;
  document.getElementById('score').value = correct

Comment: Exactly...I've added the 2nd question check for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. You have several problems. Check teh code and feel free to ask anything:

```js
var quizArray = [{
  answer: 'ashente'
}, {
  answer: 'green'
}, {
  answer: 'yes'
}, {
  answer: 'love'
}, {
  answer: 'both'
}, {
  answer: 'chopper'
}, {
  answer: 'heavens'
}]

function answer() {
  var correct = 0;
  var wrong = 0;
  var questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question");

  for (i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].value.toLowerCase() == quizArray[i].answer.toLowerCase()) {
      correct += 1;
      document.getElementById('score').value = correct
    } else {
      wrong += 1;
      document.getElementById('wrong').value = wrong

    }
  }


}




(function(){
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", answer);
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <h5>What do you say to begin a game in No Game No Life?</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question1'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>What color is Mumen Rider's helmet in One Punch Man?</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question2'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Are Goku's new Super Saiyan Forms too ridiculous?</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question3' placeholder='Yes or No?'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>What is the Answer to Life's Problems?</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question4' placeholder='Love or Fear?'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>In Season 2 of SAO, is the main character a girl, boy, or both?</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question5'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Who is the best character in One Piece?</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question6'>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Finish this quote from Gurren Lagann, "TO THE ( )!!!!!"</h5>
  <input class='question' id='question7'>
</div>
<input id='button' type='submit' value="Do you even anime?">


<span class='correct'><label for='score'>CORRECT</label><input type='text' id='score'></span>
<span class='wrong'><label for='wrong'>WRONG</label><input type='text' id='wrong'></span>
```

I will calrify some points anyway. As you could see, the main difference is the size of the js. You had teh same piece of code for each question, when you are in a situation like this, you should use a function or a loop. This is part of the [DRY concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). So taking all the questions in an array and iterate over them is easier than create a piece of code for each one.

I added the function `toLowerCase` because is annoying failing answers only if you missed that detail. Using this function is not necessary, it's up to you.

In the HTML part I must remark that if you have a button that sends a `form` you should create an `input` which `type` is `submit`. HTML `button` is not properly for submitting a form. It can do the job, but it is not the correct way.

You use inputs to show the score, but, instead it will be better to use plain text. Again, it's not bad but it's handier.